# IBM Watson Alchemy news iOS SDK Swift

Tags: swift3, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

The IBM Watson iOS SDK using the Alchemy News service on Bluemix returns a string result which requires parsing to pull out the fields like url and cleaned title. ref: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk

I pull the string into an array and parse it in swift3 using some string methods but this is pretty ordinary and can produce unpredictable results

Is there a more elegant approach where I can access specific fields, like the url and cleaned title which I am passing to a UITableViewCell to select and segue to the url link.

```
sample code:
let alchemyDataNews = AlchemyDataNews(apiKey: apiKey)
let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }
let start = "now-14d" // 7 day ago
let end = "now" // today
let query = ["count": "15",
                            "dedup": "true",
                            "q.enriched.url.title": "[IBM]",
                            "return":  "enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title" "enriched.url.title,enriched.url.entities.entity.text,enriched.url.entities.entity.type"]
```

Also I have noticed the search string [IBM] has a prefix of 0, i.e. 0[IBM] and have also seen an "A". What do these prefixes mean and where are they documented

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can access the fields from a returned payload.

```
    alchemyDataNews.getNews(from: "now-4d", to: "now", query: queryDict, failure: failWithError) { news in

        for doc in (news.result?.docs)! {
            var cleanedTitle = doc.source?.enriched?.url?.cleanedTitle
            var author = doc.source?.enriched?.url?.author
            var title = doc.source?.enriched?.url?.title
        }}
```

Also, here is a nice API reference link for alchemy data which contains all of the request parameters and filters.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemydata-news/api/v1/

Comment: Thank you Vince, that was just what I was hoping for. I've looked at that documentation and failed to find the Swift syntax using the correct parameters and filters. Maybe I missed it but now that you have provided this example I can easily use all the parameters and filters. If this Swift syntax is document anywhere I'd appreciate the link